# populate HTML table from array values

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dealer_id] => 5924
            [DealerName] => I Speed Motors
            [mmv_id] => 1
            [model_decision] => Straight Through
            [CCStatus] => CC Pending
            [created_at] => 2020-10-09 10:04:36
            [count] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dealer_id] => 7942
            [DealerName] => Suriya Motors LLP
            [mmv_id] => 1
            [model_decision] => Referred to Credit
            [CCStatus] => CC Approved
            [created_at] => 2020-10-09 11:39:34
            [count] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dealer_id] => 7942
            [DealerName] => Suriya Motors LLP
            [mmv_id] => 1
            [model_decision] => Form Received at Chola
            [CCStatus] => CC Rejected
            [created_at] => 2020-10-09 10:04:23
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```

from this array populate count in correct column based on current time accordingly in below table format

```
|Dealer Name    |Status                           |11.00am|1.00pm|3.00pm|5.00pm|7.00pm|9.00pm|
|Dealer 1       |CC Pending                       |       |      |      |      |      |      |
                |CC Rejected                      |       |      |      |      |      |      |
                |CC Expired                       |       |      |      |      |      |      |
                |<Model Decision if CC Approved>  |       |      |      |      |      |      |
```

My output which is wrong

```
|Dealer Name      |Status                |11.00am|1.00pm|3.00pm|5.00pm|7.00pm|9.00pm|

|Suriya Motors LLP|CC Pending            |       |      |      |      |      |      |
                  |CC Rejected           |       |      |      |      |      |      |
                  |CC Expired            |       |      |      |      |      |      |
                  |Referred to Credit    |   1   |      |      |      |      |      |

|I Speed Motors   |CC Pending            |   2   |      |      |      |      |      |
                  |CC Rejected           |       |      |      |      |      |      |
                  |CC Expired            |       |      |      |      |      |      |

|Suriya Motors LLP|CC Pending            |       |      |      |      |      |      |
                  |CC Rejected           |   1   |      |      |      |      |      |
                  |CC Expired            |       |      |      |      |      |      |
```

Expected output if the current time is 3.00pm

```
|Dealer Name      |Status                |11.00am|1.00pm|3.00pm|5.00pm|7.00pm|9.00pm|

|Suriya Motors LLP|CC Pending            |       |      |      |      |      |      |
                  |CC Rejected           |       |      |   1  |      |      |      |
                  |CC Expired            |       |      |      |      |      |      |
                  |Referred to Credit    |       |      |   1  |      |      |      |

|I Speed Motors   |CC Pending            |       |      |   2  |      |      |      |
                  |CC Rejected           |       |      |      |      |      |      |
                  |CC Expired            |       |      |      |      |      |      |
```

My Code

```
    $body = "<html>
                            <head>
                            <style>
                            table, th, td {
                              border: 1px solid black;
                              border-collapse: collapse;
                              text-align: center;
                            }
                            </style>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                
                            
                            
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Dealer Name</th><th>Status</th><th>11.00am</th><th>1.00pm</th><th>3.00pm</th><th>5.00pm</th><th>7.00pm</th><th>9.00pm</th>
                                    </tr>";
                                    
                                    foreach($dealerCount as $key => $value){
                                        $dealerName = $modeldecision = $ccapproved = $ccpending = $ccrejected = $ccexpired = '';
                                        $dealerName = $value['DealerName'];
                                        if($value['CCStatus'] == "CC Approved"){
                                            $modeldecision = $value['model_decision'];
                                            $ccapproved = $value['count'];
                                        }
                                        if($value['CCStatus'] == "CC Pending"){
                                            $ccpending = $value['count'];
                                        }
                                        if($value['CCStatus'] == "CC Rejected"){
                                            $ccrejected = $value['count'];
                                        }
                                        if($value['CCStatus'] == "CC Expired"){
                                            $ccexpired = $value['count'];
                                        }
                                        $body .= "<tr>
                                            <td rowspan='4'>$dealerName</td><td>CC Pending</td><td>$ccpending</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>     
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>CC Rejected</td><td>$ccrejected</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>CC Expired</td><td>$ccexpired</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                                        </tr>";
                                $body .= "<tr>";
                                $body .= "<td>$modeldecision</td>";
                                $body .= "<td>$ccapproved</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                                        </tr>  ";
                                    }  
                                $body .= "</table>";
                                $body .= "<body>";
                                $body .= "<html>";
```

Comment: Why don't you use a HTML template, instead of putting PHP code inside HTML?

Comment: Not possible to use template it has to be in mail body

Comment: This is easier if your reorganize your array with each key being each dealer ID (instead of the index) and put matching dealer ID data inside that. Something like `['7942' => [[CCStatus' => 'CC Approved', 'created_at' => '2020-10-09 11:39:34'], [CCStatus' => 'CC Rejected', 'created_at' => '2020-10-09 10:04:23']];`. You can then loop through each dealer first, then each of it's arrays to build the table to match your expected output.